# Simple syntax for testing Validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, validation

I'm looking for clean and short code to test validations in Rails Unittests.

Currently I do something like this

```
test "create thing without name" do
    assert_raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
        Thing.create! :param1 => "Something", :param2 => 123
    end
end
```

I guess there is a better way that also shows the validation message?

**Solution:**

My current solution without an additional frameworks is:

```
test "create thing without name" do
    thing = Thing.new :param1 => "Something", :param2 => 123
    assert thing.invalid?
    assert thing.errors.on(:name).any?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will try rspec and the others some time. For now I help myself with assert(record.invalid?) and assert_equal([], record.errors.full_messages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention what testing framework that you're using. Many have macros that make testing activerecord a snap.

Here's the "long way" to do it without using any test helpers:

```
thing = Thing.new :param1 => "Something", :param2 => 123
assert !thing.valid?
assert_match /blank/, thing.errors.on(:name)
```

Comment: I use only plain Rails at the moment.

Comment: As of Rails 3 there's no "on" method for ActiveModel::Errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526499/undefined-method-on-for-actionmodel

Comment: This answer might be dated, but `assert_match` does not work on an array.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Rails (v5) with MiniTest

```rb
test "create thing without name" do
    thing = Thing.new :param1 => "Something", :param2 => 123
    assert thing.invalid?
    assert thing.errors.added? :name, :blank
end
```

[https://devdocs.io/rails~5.2/activemodel/errors](https://devdocs.io/rails%7E5.2/activemodel/errors)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 2.0.5, and when I want to assert that a model will fail validation, I check the [`errors.full_messages` method](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.0.3/ActiveRecord/Errors/full_messages), and compare it to an array of expected messages.

```
created = MyModel.new
created.field1 = "Some value"
created.field2 = 123.45
created.save

assert_equal(["Name can't be blank"], created.errors.full_messages)
```

To assert that validation succeeds, I just compare to an empty array. You can do something very similar to check that a Rails controller has no error messages after a create or update request.

```
assert_difference('MyModel.count') do
  post :create, :my_model => {
    :name => 'Some name'
  }
end

assert_equal([], assigns(:my_model).errors.full_messages)
assert_redirected_to my_model_path(assigns(:my_model))
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using Rails 3.2.1 and up, I prefer using the [added?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-added-3F) method:

```
assert record.errors.added? :name, :blank
```

I use a test helper that looks like this:

```
def assert_invalid(record, options)
  assert_predicate record, :invalid?

  options.each do |attribute, message|
    assert record.errors.added?(attribute, message), "Expected #{attribute} to have the following error: #{message}"
  end
end
```

Which allows me to write tests like this:

```
test "should be invalid without a name" do
  user = User.new(name: '')

  assert_invalid user, name: :blank
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also [accept_values_for](https://github.com/bogdan/accept_values_for) gem.
It allows to do something like this:

```
describe User do

  subject { User.new(@valid_attributes)}

  it { should accept_values_for(:email, "john@example.com", "lambda@gusiev.com") }
  it { should_not accept_values_for(:email, "invalid", nil, "a@b", "john@.com") }
end
```

In this way you can test really complicated validations easily

Answer (score 0):

You could give the [rspec-on-rails-matchers](http://github.com/ohammersmith/rspec-on-rails-matchers) a try. Provides you with syntax like:

```
@thing.should validates_presence_of(:name)
```

Comment: The page says: Don't use me. I'm out of date and I break shoulda. Shoulda works with rspec now. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was added but the [#where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481502/simple-syntax-for-testing-validation-errors) method makes it easy to target a specific error without having to rely on the text of the message.

```
refute @thing.valid?
assert @thing.errors.where(:name, :invalid).present?
```