# Undefined method 'on' for ActionModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-1.9

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#new

Showing .../app/views/users/form/_new.haml where line #7 raised:

undefined method `on' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fb599ec6610>
```

The code in line 7 is:

```
7:   = errors_for user, :first_name
```

And the application_helper.rb:

```
def errors_for(model, field)
  error = case errors = model.errors.on(field)
  ...
end
```

'on' is a [default method in ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M000306). Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3, then the problem is that there's no "on" method for the Errors class anymore.  I think you're supposed to use "get" now.  So:

```
error = case errors = model.errors.get(field)
```

Or...

```
error = case errors = model.errors[field]
```

Comment: Basically "on" used to be an alias for [], and they changed it to "get".  I'd just use [] (which would work in both Rails 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1):

I checked my user and `u.errors` is an `ActiveRecord::Errors`, while I see you have an `ActiveModel::Error`, I would work on that.

Then I don't understand `case errors =` statement in your helper, I'm curious to know how you implemented that part...

Comment: I was wondering about that, too. But when I run User.new in the rails console, everything works fine. The code is from Teambox (https://github.com/teambox/teambox/blob/dev/app/helpers/application_helper.rb), trying to run it locally.

Comment: the case statement makes more sense now (though I think if you have 2 errors on the same field you loose the second?).

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to get the code running, I didn't write it. ;) I removed the whole statement, but it still returns with the same error. No clue what's wrong there. Especially that it checks on the model and not ActiveRecords.

Comment: I tried to install the repo but I had some problems with the gem versions so I gave up, did you get it straight running?

Comment: Yes, took me quite some time to get all the right gem versions together. Here's my fork: https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/teambox

Comment: still I can't bundle, I'm not going to spend time to find the right configuration (though it's weird), can you debug and check the instance of `@user`, is it an `ActiveRecord`? - and lastly, can you ask somebody in the project to answer your question?

Comment: sorry I couldn't do any better, if you find the problem you can answer you own question and mark it as solved

Comment: Well, I kind of gave up for the moment as well. Will wait for the next version on GitHub to see if it works better.